# Mongoose weird error duplication in array of subschemas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose

I'm testing a couple of schemas using mongoose and I'm getting the same error twice on a subschema.

This is my model:

```
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: isEmail
  },
  order_code: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  status: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  products: [{
    product_id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      rel: 'Product',
      required: true
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  }]
})

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema)

module.exports = Order
```

This is my test for an error on quantity in the products array:

```
test('Should be invalid if malformed product', () => {
  const malformed = getValidOrder() // <- This just returns a valid order object
  malformed.products[0].quantity = 'whatup' // <- Setting up a wrong quantity

  const m = new Order( malformed )
  const v = m.validateSync()

  expect(howManyKeys(v.errors)).toBe(1) // <- here the test fails since there are two errors instead of one
})
```

I get this two errors: `products.0.quantity` and `products.0.products.0.quantity`, and as you can see the second one just has a really weird pattern.

Is this a common mongoose pattern for subschemas or is it something wrong with the Schema? 
I know errors in subschemas are passed to the parent schema from reading the docs.